# CATransaction Animations Occurring With setDisableActions:YES

Tags: ios, animation, ios7, core-animation

I have a number of CALayer/CAShapeLayer/CATextLayer objects that need to be modified simultaneously, but only a subset should animate. For those layers that I do not wish to animate, I wrap the update in CATransaction calls like this:

```
- (void) setPlayerName:(NSString *)playerName
{
    _playerName = playerName;

    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];

    [self updateNameLayer]; // Layer property updates happen in here

    [CATransaction commit];

    // Update the screen
    [self setNeedsLayout];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

It wasn't until I used a `[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];` outside of `CATransaction` begin/commit calls that I realized animations could be affected on separate objects that were set to animate at the same time. In that case, all of my animations for that update were disabled.

The solution, I thought, was to explicitly wrap each update in `CATransaction` begin/commit calls to localize the setDisableActions: call to that transaction. Even after doing this, it still seems that the animations are either all or nothing. Sounds to me like I don't have a good enough understanding of how CATransaction works.

What is the correct way to handle several, simultaneous CALayer implicitly-animated property updates but only animate a subset of them? These update calls and layers are scattered across multiple objects.

Comment: If you're trying to mix and match animated and non-animated changes that are buried within each other, this approach, as if you've seemingly found, won't work.  Take a look at `[CALayer actionForKey:]` for a way to disable animations for specific properties.

Comment: If this is the case, would you suggest stripping out all these CATransaction blocks and use `actionForKey:` right before the property update instead?

Comment: You use actionForKey to disable all animations of a given layer property.  It's something you define in a CALayer subclass, not something you call.

Comment: Actually you can use `actionForKey:` in very subtle ways to disable animations of a given layer property _sometimes_ and not at other times. However, I strongly doubt that you need to worry about that here; you should continue try to figure out why your results don't match the results of the test code in my answer. Either that or, as I've already recommended, abandon implicit animation and use explicit CABasicAnimation-type layer animation where you are in total charge.

Answer (score 4):

Certainly what you're trying to do *can* work. For example:

```
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
    self.lay1.position = CGPointMake(300,300);
    [CATransaction commit];

    self.lay2.position = CGPointMake(300,300);
```

Those two layers move to the same place, but one of them is animated and the other isn't.

The fact that your code *isn't* working the way you want can't be explained without further information. (For example, you may be giving a layer contradictory commands, thus causing the animation to be canceled.) But you are definitely on a legitimate track. If you find this too daunting, however, I recommend just abandoning implicit layer animation and instead using CABasicAnimation and friends.

Comment: Ok, so the CATransactions are indeed separate when you wrap them in begin/commit calls (From the CATransaction class reference: "The transaction is nested within the thread’s current transaction, if there is one."). So, the fact that I'm doing many of them simultaneously is not the problem, it's that I'm likely contradicting myself somewhere. Hm...

Comment: That's what I'm _guessing_. All I did was to prove that this works for the simple case. :)

Comment: K, so the problem is with simultaneous animations, not sequential like in your example. Imagine your example happening in two different objects simultaneously, with one having disabled actions and the other not. That's where things are getting borked up for me. I'm struggling to find a way to debug this by looking for contradictory commands.

Comment: My example does happen in two different objects simultaneously one having disabled actions and the other not. `lay1` and `lay2` are two different things. I could have wrapped both `position` settings in explicit CATransaction blocks (I did test that) and it still works as expected: one animates, the other doesn't. I am not seeing the "all or nothing" you are reporting.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my fault - I mean the properties of the two layers are being updated by different objects, so those CATransactions would be happening in parallel.

Comment: "In parallel"? How? Code runs in succession, not in parallel. Unless you use a background thread. Are you saying there's a _threading_ issue here?

Comment: Is there a possibility that your code is so spaghettified that you are saying `[CATransaction begin]` inside an existing CATransaction block? That is okay, but keep in mind that _settings are inherited_. So if you say `setDisableActions:YES` in one, you must say `setDisableActions:NO` in the nested one if you want to override - it doesn't override implicitly.

Comment: Eek, very bad word choice - I should not have used the word parallel. Everything's happening on the main thread. I'll dig in to see if I'm accidentally nesting CATransaction blocks - good tip.